# Unable to use file path literals being passed as list values

Tags: python

I have a list of file paths formed in this loop:

```
for each_file in os.listdir(my_dir):
    fp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(my_dir, each_file))
    if fp.endswith('.txt'):
        my_list += [fp]
```

`fp` looks like `H:\Dir\1. DirOne\2. DirTwo\file.txt`

Then in a later function, I pass the `my_list` as an argument and for debugging I can print each item in it, to which valid literal file paths (with `\` and not `\\`) are printed.

However, when I send each path to `arcpy.dosomething()` [not a real function btw], it errors and prints the file path back but some of the `\` have become odd characters (`˥`). I know this is occurring because those `\` in question are acting as the escape character since the true value in the file path is something like `\2. DirName\3. AnotherDir`. Those `\#.` are the problems.

Now to test this I am able to do a single file path using `r'file path'` but how do I replicate this with list values such that:

```
for path in my_list:
    # I want to mimic the use of r' ' against the iterable
    arcpy.dosomething(r'path')
```

I've tried `path.replace("\\", "\\\\")` but the `\#.` turn into an odd symbol (`˥`) still. I've even tried:

`path = r''+path+''`

&

```
find = r'\\'
replace = r'\\\\'
path = re.sub(find, replace, path)
```

If I use `repr()` I get closer to what I need:

```
path = repr(path)
output: \x02 #where the \#. were and all other \ are now \\
```

All produce same result which looks like a Unicode character.

Comment: Do you actually have any string literals? That would be important to include in your question. Strings that contain backslashes don't just spontaneously get parsed as control sequences.

Comment: Can you show your actual output rather than saying "odd symbols"?

Comment: @JoshLee example string shown as `fp` in edit.

Comment: @cdarke Updated post. Symbol is `˥`.

Comment: You say you print the string and it prints OK, but you send the string into some function and it returns a different string altogether. We need to see that function.

Comment: @MarkRansom [Here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm). Value that changes is the `in_raster` string.

Comment: If you print `repr(fp)` what does that look like? Can you give an actual file rather than the generic that's currently in the question?